# PHP form not working on new server

Tags: php

I have created a form for my website by following a tutorial at tutorialzine

I have this form working nicely on one of my websites but when I tried to install the form on a new website the form fields are full of script and it doesn't work. I have put the same form on both servers to demonstrate the problem.

Working form:
http://lagunapools.com.au/crowntest/contact.php

Not working:
http://crowndoor.com.au/crowntest/contact.php

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is the tutorial i followed: http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/fancy-contact-form/

Comment: Better if you can simply solve the error, will be Good Practice ! :D

Answer (score 2):

You have different error reporting configuration with those servers. The "working" one is hiding the errors (or logging them to a file), the "not working" one is displaying the errors, or in this case notices, directly in the HTML code.

error_reporting and display_errors are the php configuration directives that affect this.

Also, you could (should) use error_log directive to log the errors to a file instead of displaying them in the code.

Comment: Thanks. So turning off the error_reporting will resolve this? Is it possible to do this in the php file or does it need to be done by the webmaster?

Comment: turning if off will hide the issues. It would be better to a) first redirect error messages to a log file and then b) actually fix them.

Comment: error reporting level can be set in .php, but for some notices this will have no effect as those are evaluated at compile time (so before your script is executed). Also, it might be possible to set it with .htaccess, depending on your server software and its configuration.

Comment: I tried putting: error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); into the .php but it seems to have no effect.